# How to make a grid of buttons giving them a name (even if I create them with a "for")

Tags: python, tkinter

I recently saw a question on "how to make a grid of buttons whose size changes automatically". I found a very interesting example of code there, however, the proposed method created the buttons in a "for", which did not allow them to be set to a specific parameter. Here is this code:

```
frame = Frame(root)
Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight = 1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight = 1)
frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = N + S + E + W)
grid = Frame(frame)
grid.grid(sticky = N + S + E + W, column = 0, row = 7, columnspan = 2)
Grid.rowconfigure(frame, 7, weight = 1)
Grid.columnconfigure(frame, 0, weight = 1)

for x in range(10):
    for y in range(5):
        btn = Button(frame)
        btn.grid(column = x, row = y, sticky = N + S + E + W)

for x in range(10):
    Grid.columnconfigure(frame, x, weight = 1)

for y in range(5):
    Grid.rowconfigure(frame, y, weight = 1)
```

Could you tell me how to make each button different?

Comment: What do you mean by "make each button different"? What kind of difference are you looking for? Color? Font? Size?

Comment: What you want is a list of buttons rather than a name for each button. Using a list you can reference the index to update the buttons.

Comment: @BryanOakley  I'm looking for text and command differences.

Answer (score 1):

One issue I see here is you `import tkinter as tk` but do not use the prefix `tk.` when trying to set up your frames or buttons. This leads me to believe you may also be doing `from tkinter import *` and this is really bad idea especially when you write `grid = Frame(root)` as you are overwriting the `grid()` method one line before you actually try to use `grid()`.

By using a list of buttons we can reference the index where the button is stored and do something with it.

Se below example and let me know if you have any questions:

```
import tkinter as tk


def some_function(ndex):
    print(button_list[ndex]['text'])
    button_list[ndex].config(text='', background='black')
    print(button_list[ndex]['text'])


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
button_list = []

for x in range(15):
    root.columnconfigure(x, weight=1)
    for y in range(17):
        button_list.append(tk.Button(root))
        count = len(button_list)
        button_list[-1].config(text='{}'.format(count), command=lambda ndex=count-1: some_function(ndex))
        button_list[-1].grid(column=x, row=y, sticky='nsew')
        if x == 0:
            root.rowconfigure(y, weight=1)


root.mainloop()
```

For the fun of it and the approaching holiday here is a Jack-o'-lantern made from the code :D

[image]

To answer you question in the comments see below code:

```
import tkinter as tk


def some_function(value):
    print(value)


root = tk.Tk()
button_values = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['=', '+', '-']]
button_list = []

for ndex, sub_list in enumerate(button_values):
    root.columnconfigure(ndex, weight=1)
    for sub_ndex, value in enumerate(sub_list):
        button_list.append(tk.Button(root))
        count = len(button_list)
        button_list[-1].config(text=value, command=lambda x=value: some_function(x))
        button_list[-1].grid(column=ndex, row=sub_ndex, sticky='nsew')


root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Console after pressing each button:

```
A
B
C
=
+
-
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. What if I want to set a different text or command to each button, precisely? For example, I'd like to make the button in down right corner being a "=" which would send the result when I click on it...

Comment: That is easy. We just make a list of all the buttons you want and then use that list and index numbers to make your buttons.

Comment: @Bethoth I have added an example to my answer.

Comment: The lone thing that I still don't understand is how to give each button a different command...

Comment: Well if you want to do it dynamically you simply reference the value in a list that is related to your needs. Like if you are making a calculator. To accomplish this you need to use a nameless function called a lmabda. This allows you to write one line functions that can be used as a command. Here is an example where they do that to make a type of on screen keyboard. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53647343/how-to-change-which-tkinter-button-is-highlighted-via-arrow-keys.